# Xamarin.Forms variable navigation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

I'm currently making a stock control app for Android with Xamarin.Forms.
I have an extra page just for entering the Pruduct ID. I want to use that page in two scenarions:

1. You pick an product to add/remove them from stock
2. You pick an product to tell the office that new ones have to be ordered

After picking the product you will be redirectet to:

1. The "DetailStockmovementPage" in case 1
2. The "DetailOrderPage" in case 2

The Problem is, that the next Page **depends on what button was clicked before**.
In my ViewModel I have the following Code to navigate (for scenario 1):

```
public async Task GoToNextPage(Product product)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailStockmovementPage(product), true);
        }
```

How can I make the next Page variable? Can I define a variable "NextPage" in my ViewModel, set it from the View like "vm.NextPage = DetailStockmovementPage" and Navigate like

```
public async Task GoToNextPage(Product product)
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage(product), true);
            }
```

I know that does not work, but I think that poor try made clear what I want to achieve. I mean I could push a string for each page and make an if-query before navigating, but I don't think thats an good way to do it. How can I vary the page to be navigated to?

Comment: I'm not sure about the scenario here. Is it that you have a page with two options (scenarios 1 and 2), which both will then navigate to a new page where the user can enter the product ID and is **then** redirected to either the DetailStockmovementPage or the DetailOrderPage?

Comment: Sorry about that, I find it's very hard to explain. I have a menu page where I push either button "Stockmovement" or "Order". For both, order and stockmovement you require the "product". After selection, you go to DetailStockmovementPage OR DetailOrderPage, depending on your choice on MenuPage

Comment: OK, so your user taps either the "Stockmovement" or the "Order" button. What happens then? Do they go to a different page to select the product?

Comment: Yes, to the ProductSelectionPage (where you enter product ID). And with the ID it continues to either DetailStockmovementPage or DetailOrderPage. depending on what you clicked on MenuPage.

Comment: If you don't want to pass an identifier to the ProductSelectionPage/ViewModel which tells it where to go next, you could define an EventHandler, like, OnProductSelected.. then have the calling Page (I think that's the menu in your example) manipulate the navigation stack to go to the right Detail* page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the user's choice from the first page into the page where they select the product, and then use that information to decide which page to navigate to. For example:

In your App.cs file add an enum:

```
public enum NavTarget
{
    Order,
    Stockmovement
}
```

Define a property in your VM for the target selected in your menu page:

```
public NavTarget Target { get; set; }
```

...and use it in your navigation method:

```
public async Task GoToNextPage(Product product)
{
    if (Target == NavTarget.Stockmovement)
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailStockmovementPage(product), true);
    else
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new WhateverItsCalledPage(product), true);
}
```

Then set that property in the constructor for your ProductSelectionPage:

```
public ProductSelectionPage(NavTarget target)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // some code that sets the VM for this page
    // ...

    vm.Target = target;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that should solve it! But I have an additional question just out of curiosity: Is there a way to do it with any target page (without declaring them in the enum and the if-query)? Pushing the page itself directly like "public ProductSelectionPage(Type TargetPage){...}" (I don't know if thats the right variable type)? Something like that would make it universal and you don't have to declare it in the enum and if-query when you have an additional (third) type of page?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely can. I suggest you start using an MVVM framework, if you don't do so already. MVVMLight and MVVMCross are very popular for Xamarin. I don't know about MVVMCross, but with MVVMLight you can create a NavigationService that allows you to navigate to pages using a string key. There's a very good article here: https://mallibone.com/post/xamarin.forms-navigation-with-mvvm-light. It's using MVVMLight, but if you don't use that, it's easy enough to adapt.

Comment: If you have a Pluralsight subscription, they have a course on MVVMLight that'll get you up to speed in no time.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I will give that a try!

Comment: If you're going to try MVVMLight, be aware that there are different NuGet packages available. I use MVVMLightLibs for Xamarin.Forms with a normal PCL, and MVVMLightLibsStd for a Xamarin.Forms project using the new .NET Standard library.